# 000002 (0A000): Unsupported feature 'TAG' in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I am create a tag in the Snowflake worksheet, encountered this error:

```
000002 (0A000): Unsupported feature 'TAG'.
```

Here is the SQL statement:

```
CREATE TAG IF NOT EXISTS model_id_tag;
```

Comment: Are you running Enterprise Edition or higher, which is required to use this feature?

Comment: 6.19.0, is that Enterprise Edition?

Comment: That's just the current version of the software, not the level of your edition.  My guess is that you are not on Enterprise, or that statement would've worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CREATE TAG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-tag.html) requires Enterprise or higher edition.

Edition could be checked using WebUI by highlighting the locator:

[image]